# Purpose of the autostart-scripts directory

Tags: scripting, login, gnome3, freedesktop

A user can place `.desktop` files in his `~/.config/autostart/` directory to [run a script on login (session start) in Gnome](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8247706/393280), or indeed [any Freedesktop-compliant environment](https://specifications.freedesktop.org/autostart-spec/autostart-spec-latest.html).

But, on my openSUSE Leap 42.2 Gnome 3 system, in addition to each user's `~/.config/autostart/` directory, each user also has a `~/.config/autostart-scripts/` directory. I would assume that this directory would serve as a dumping ground for any quick and dirty scripts that a user would want to run on login without having to wrap those scripts in a `.desktop` file, but the scripts I place in that directory do not run on login.

Search engines have provided very little in the way of details about this directory. Does anyone know the purpose of the `~/.config/autostart-scripts` directory and the requirements for the scripts in it to run?

Comment: Glad that I'm not the only one wondering about this cryptic directory. Obviously your synopsis per the Freedesktop spec for the `autostart` directory is straight from the Freedesktop docs; and as for `autostart-scripts`, KDE Plasma 5 behaves exactly as you assume: it executes any executables in that directory. Not knowing much about GNOME 3, I don't know why it didn't "work" (what does "work" really even mean here?) for you there, but Plasma 5 observes that behavior.

Comment: Indeed, Plasma 5 has `autostart-scripts` hardcoded in its source (along with `plasma-workspace/shutdown` and `plasma-workspace/env`): [here it is on GitHub](https://github.com/KDE/plasma-desktop/blob/b368bd1b04b4013b18e400666d0bc79b6c4b30f0/kcms/autostart/autostart.cpp#L151). Googling this directory name yields absolutely nothing, though, so it's not part of any standard. I assume the KDE folks just chose it kind of arbitrarily

Answer (score 3):

Because (as [user villapx discovered](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/348321/13308#comment905657_348321)) [KDE Plasma 5 has this `autostart-scripts` directory in its source](https://github.com/KDE/plasma-desktop/blob/b368bd1b04b4013b18e400666d0bc79b6c4b30f0/kcms/autostart/autostart.cpp#L151), I am assuming that it is an undocumented feature of Plasma 5 and that I was running this profile under KDE at one point.

I was able to tweak my system for other Desktop Environments to make it work as I believe KDE uses it. To do this, I added a system autostart Desktop file at `/etc/xdg/autostart/exec-autostart`:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Exec=autostart-exec.sh
Icon=system-run
NotShowIn=KDE
Terminal=false
TerminalOptions=
Type=Application
```

This referenced a script that would call each script in the `autostart-scripts` directory (using the directory determination from [the Autostart spec](https://specifications.freedesktop.org/autostart-spec/autostart-spec-latest.html)):

```
#!/bin/sh

shopt -s nullglob # Ensure shell expansion with 0 files expands to an empty list, rather than trying to read the "*.sh" file

if [ -z "$XDG_CONFIG_HOME" ]; then
    XDG_CONFIG_HOME=~/.config
fi
for f in "$XDG_CONFIG_HOME/autostart-scripts/"*.sh; do
    test -x "$f" && . "$f" || true
done
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm adding some extra information here for general googlers on this dir.. It seems KDE changed the workings of this dir in 2021 (without telling people widely, much to the ire of some), and "unilaterally" moved this dir to 'old-autostart-scripts'. Then a .desktop file was created in /home/user/.config/autostarts dir for each script."

https://bugs.kde.org/show_bug.cgi?id=436439   old bug report
https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=267220   discussion
https://invent.kde.org/plasma/plasma-workspace/-/merge_requests/736  official statement:

> Currently the scripts inside of $XDG_CONFIG_HOME/autostart-scripts are
> not run in systemd mode (https://bugs.kde.org/show_bug.cgi?id=433987).
> This PR migrates them to simple .desktop files inside of
> XDG_CONFIG_HOME/autostart so that they can be handled in both classic
> and systemd boot mode. **This way they can also be seen by other desktop
> environments (autostart-scripts was a kde-only feature). And you can
> even define login scripts at the system level thanks to the xdg config
> hierarchy** The migration will create a corresponding .desktop file for
> each existing login script. If the login script was a symlink, it will
> be deleted and the .desktop file will point to the source. The KCM is
> also updated to use this new format. Login scripts are still visible
> as such (using a kde service type to distinguish them). Instead of
> creating a symlink to $XDG_CONFIG_HOME/autostart-scripts, adding a new
> script now creates a .desktop file in $XDG_CONFIG_HOME/autostart This
> also separates pre-startup (env) scripts from login scripts in the UI.
> They were previously supported but merged in the same category.

It seems to be automatically moving files still in 2023.